# Запятая или двоеточие в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

А вот если бы фашисты победили в той войне, тогда что же (, или :) преступниками объявили бы тех, кого мы сегодня называем героями?

Скажите, пожалуйста, после слов "что же" какой знак препинания следует поставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот если бы фашисты победили в той войне, **тогда что же,** преступниками объявили бы тех, кого мы сегодня называем героями?

Здесь значение такое: **тогда что же было бы**, преступниками объявили бы тех...

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=131#pp131

Слова ***что, а что, что же,*** обозначающие вопросы, и слова как, как же, что же, выражающие удивление, подтверждение, согласие и т. п., за которыми **следует предложение,** раскрывающее их конкретный смысл (после них делается пауза), **отделяются запятой.**

***Что же мне, стреляться из-за этой пропажи?*** — неполное предложение со значением ‘что же мне делать?’.